# Volume Rendering: How can I turn a .raw file into an opengl-friendly isosurface?

Tags: opengl, textures, volume-rendering

I want to create a 3D visualizer of .raw volume medical datasets using marching tetrahedra.

I found [this implementation on GPL license](http://www.siafoo.net/snippet/100) that looks nice and is based on the info by Paul Bourke, but I don't know how to make work with a .raw file, which I've found [people load as a 3d texture](http://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/ubbthreads.php?ubb=showflat&Number=299805).

```
//assuming that the data at hand is a 256x256x256 unsigned byte data
int XDIM=256, YDIM=256, ZDIM=256;
const int size = XDIM*YDIM*ZDIM;
bool LoadVolumeFromFile(const char* fileName) {

    FILE *pFile = fopen(fileName,"rb");
   if(NULL == pFile) {
    return false;
   }

   GLubyte* pVolume=new GLubyte[size]; //<- here pVolume is a 1D byte array 
   fread(pVolume,sizeof(GLubyte),size,pFile);
   fclose(pFile);

   // now pVolume is passed to a 3d texture 

    //load data into a 3D texture


glGenTextures(1, &textureID);
   glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_3D, textureID);

   // set the texture parameters
   glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_3D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP);
   glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_3D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP);
   glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_3D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_R, GL_CLAMP);
   glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_3D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
   glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_3D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

   glTexImage3D(GL_TEXTURE_3D,0,GL_INTENSITY,XDIM,YDIM,ZDIM,0,GL_LUMINANCE,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,pVolume);
   delete [] pVolume;
   return true;




}
```

I don't know if I should either:
a) access the values directly from pValue
b) access them after loading them to a 3D texture

I have no idea of how I'm supposed to index pVolume to get the isosurface intensity at each x,y,z. if pVolume is a 1D array. I know x,y coordinates are mapped from a 1D array using a divide and a module, but how would I map x,y,z?

On the other hand, If I load the .raw file as a 3d texture would

> glTexCoord3f

give me the isovalue at a given x,y,z?

**Clarification: The question isn't "can OpenGL draw an isosurface directly from this?" the question is how to index the isolevels on the .raw geometry, which is needed to evaluate each tetrahedron properly. On the image one can see that each tetrahedron case is marked based on whether the isosurface is above or below it. The isosurface is indexed on it's x,y,z coordinates on the .raw file, how can I access it for each x,y,z on the dataset? Will glTexCoord3f give me its intensity on a given x,y,z? Is it better to do a x,y,z conversion from the pVolume array directly?**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The isosurface is indexed on it's x,y,z coordinates on the .raw file, how can I access it for each x,y,z on the dataset?

By loading the image as a 3D array and indexing it. Not by loading it as an OpenGL texture.

> Will glTexCoord3f give me its intensity on a given x,y,z?

No. As [the documentation states](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/), `glTexCoord3f` simply provides a set of texture coordinates to the next vertex to be issued. It returns nothing, it doesn't cause anything to happen yet. All it does is set state within OpenGL.

> Is it better to do a x,y,z conversion from the pVolume array directly?

Yes. Information in OpenGL should generally travel in one direction: from the user to the screen. OpenGL functions exist for you to feed OpenGL information that it will use to render something. That's how OpenGL works best.

Any kind of back-tracking (reading images back to the CPU, etc) is a slow path.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're confusing a few things here. OpenGL is not a image processing library. It's a rasterizer API. 3D Textures are not meant as something you load data to and are given arbitrary access. You load 3D textures to map them onto surfaces, or use them in direct volume rendering.

Extracting isosurfaces is outside the scope of OpenGL.

RAW file just means that there is no header and you must know the data layout before being able to do something with it. You need to know

- width
- height
- depth
- bytes per value
  The value(s) at x,y,z can then be found at the data offset

  (width*height*z + width*y + z)*(bytes)

Isovalue just means all pixels of the data set equal to a given value. Normally you're interested in pixels which are neighboured by each a pixel below and above isovalue. For efficient determination first determine the gradient of the scalar field for each pixel. Then you test the neighbour pixels along the gradient if they're above or below the isovalue. No OpenGL involved here!

Comment: I'm not confusing OpenGL's functionality, you're assuming too much. I don't want OpenGL to extract an isosurface, I know it isn't an image processing library. I want to evaluate if the isosurface is below or above any given vertex in any given tetrahedron to know how to draw its faces. The question, put it other way, is if I can do it after loading the raw file on a 3D texture, indexed by x,y,z coordinates. I haven't worked with textures in more than a year, so my knowledge of them is quite rusty.

Comment: Please elaborate on this: bytes per value The value(s) at x,y,z can then be found at the data offset

(width*height*z + width*y + z)*(bytes)

Comment: I know this to be false, though: "Textures are not meant as something you load data to and are given arbitrary access.  You load 3D textures to map them onto surfaces, or use them in direct volume rendering." Textures can be multipurpose data too, they can be used for purposes different than mapping images to surfaces.

Comment: @omgzor: Well, you can use textures as arbitrary data storage to be sampled from shaders. But this happens on the GPU side, not client side. OpenGL makes a terrible image store for client side operations. Bytes per value just means: How many bytes there are to a single value (i.e. sizeof(...)). This is a vital parameter for raw files. It may be 8 bits (1 byte), 16 bits (2 bytes), etc.